# how to do audio live streaming from server? and How to Download Audio File in Background with live listening?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I want to play audio files like .mp3, .aif, .m4a, .m4v and .aac through http live streaming.
I tried with AvAudioplayer ,but its not supported. also Download this file in backgrounnd.Any Solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The AVAudioPlayer class does not provide support for streaming audio
>   based on HTTP URL's. The URL used with initWithContentsOfURL: must be
>   a File URL (file://). That is, a local path

See a this : [Technical Note QA 1634](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1634/_index.html)

As a above. AVAudioPlayer not supported Streaming Service via HTTP. you must using a AVPlayer. Here is a official sample code.

Here: [StitchedStreamPlayer](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/StitchedStreamPlayer/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010092-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2)

This is the underlying code. but, this code mp4 live streaming. you should change to url as mp3. it's fine working. If you have code that directly refer to implementation. or the various codes for github.

Comment: how to do with audio ?

Comment: In StreamingView.xib movieURLTextfield fill HTTP URL. and clicked Load Movie. If loaded mp3 completed, black screen will appear and you can playable. I now tested iOS7.1. It's fine working.

Answer (score 0):

Try core audio based Audio Player: [here](https://github.com/douban/DOUAudioStreamer).

Just see the examples to use.

In my opinion, this will resolve your problem.

Hopefully it will help you.